# Consulta al grabar una tabla

Tags: android

esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, tengo un problema que al grabar los datos y traspasarlo a la tabla me graba dos veces más, este es código que utilizo.

```
package com.example.prueba;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;


public class Frmmarca extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText et_busqueda, et_filas, et_tipo, et_marca, et_modelo, colFilas, colTipo, colMarca, colModelo, et_activo;
Button cmdingresar, modificar, btn_eliminar, btn_limpiar, btn_salir;
TableLayout tbldatos;
private String[]header={"N° Filas","Marca","Tipo","Modelo"};
private ArrayList<String[]> rows=new ArrayList<>();
private TableRow tableRow;
private TableDynamic tableDynamic;
private AsyncHttpClient cliente;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_frmmarca);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    et_busqueda = findViewById(R.id.txtbusqueda5);
    et_filas = findViewById(R.id.txtitem);
    et_filas.setEnabled(false);
    et_marca = findViewById(R.id.txtmarca);
    et_tipo = findViewById(R.id.txttipo);
    et_modelo = findViewById(R.id.txtmodelo);
    et_activo = findViewById(R.id.txtactivo5);
    cmdingresar = findViewById(R.id.cmdingresar);
    modificar = findViewById(R.id.cmdmodificar);
    btn_eliminar = findViewById(R.id.btn_eliminar);
    btn_limpiar = findViewById(R.id.btn_limpiar);
    btn_salir = findViewById(R.id.btn_salir);
    tbldatos = findViewById(R.id.tbldatos);
    tableDynamic = new TableDynamic(tbldatos, getApplicationContext());
    tableDynamic.addHeader(header);
    tableDynamic.addData(getClients());
    tableDynamic.backgroundHeader(Color.BLUE);
    tableDynamic.backgroundData(Color.RED, Color.YELLOW);
    tableDynamic.lineColor(Color.BLACK);
    tableDynamic.textColorData(Color.WHITE);
    tableDynamic.textColorHeader(Color.MAGENTA);
    cliente = new AsyncHttpClient();
    et_marca.requestFocus();
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    llenarSpinner();

    cmdingresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ejecutarServicio("http://192.168.*.*/oficina/insertar_vehiculos.php");
        }
    });

    modificar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            modificardatos("http://192.168.*.*/oficina/editar_vehiculos.php");
        }
    });

    btn_eliminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            eliminardatos("http://192.168.*.*/oficina/eliminar_vehiculos.php");
        }
    });

    btn_limpiar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            limpiardatos();
        }
    });

    btn_salir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            salir();
        }
    });
}

public void marca (View View) {
    et_tipo.requestFocus();
}

public void tipo (View view) {
    et_modelo.requestFocus();
}

public void modelo (View view) {
    if (cmdingresar.equals(false)) {
        modificar.requestFocus();
    } else {
        cmdingresar.requestFocus();
    }
}

private ArrayList<String[]> getClients(){
    return rows;
}

private void ejecutarServicio (String URL) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Datos grabados satisfactoriamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            datos();
            insertar();
            llenarSpinner();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String a = "1";
            et_activo.setText(a);
            parametros.put("Tipo_Vehiculo",et_tipo.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Marca_Vehiculo",et_marca.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Modelo_Vehiculo",et_modelo.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Activo",et_activo.getText().toString());
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

public void datos (){
    String[]item = new String[]{et_filas.getText().toString(),et_marca.getText().toString(),et_tipo.getText().toString(),et_modelo.getText().toString()};
    tableDynamic.addItems(item);
}

public void insertar(){
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message2).setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
    builder.setMessage("¿Desea seguir ingresando?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //int b = 1;
            //int val1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(et_filas.getText()));
            //int val2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(b));
            //int suma = val1 + val2;
            //String valorTotal = Integer.toString(suma);
            //et_filas.setText(valorTotal);
            et_tipo.setText("");
            et_modelo.setText("");
            et_tipo.requestFocus();
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            et_tipo.setText("");
            et_marca.setText("");
            et_modelo.setText("");
            et_marca.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setTitle("Oficina");
    alert.show();
}

private void llenarSpinner(){
    try {
        String url = "http://192.168.*.*/oficina/buscar_vehiculos.php";
        cliente.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                Log.d("WEB", "onSuccess: " + statusCode);
                if (statusCode == 200){
                    mostrardatos();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Log.d("WEB", "onFailure: " + statusCode + "\nError: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void mostrardatos (){
    String url = "http://192.168.*.*/oficina/buscar_vehiculos.php";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    LayoutInflater reg1 = getLayoutInflater();
                    View registro = reg1.inflate(R.layout.tabla,null, false);
                    colFilas=registro.findViewById(R.id.colFilas);
                    colMarca=registro.findViewById(R.id.colMarca);
                    colTipo=registro.findViewById(R.id.colTipo);
                    colModelo=registro.findViewById(R.id.colModelo);
                    colFilas.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Filas"));
                    colMarca.setText(jsonObject.getString("Marca_Vehiculo"));
                    colTipo.setText(jsonObject.getString("Tipo_Vehiculo"));
                    colModelo.setText(jsonObject.getString("Modelo_Vehiculo"));
                    tbldatos.addView(registro);
                }
                int j = 0;
                for (int x = 0; x <= tbldatos.getChildCount(); x++) {
                    int suma = x + j;
                    et_filas.setText("" + suma);
                }
                //int b = 1;
                //int val1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(et_filas.getText()));
                //int val2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(b));
                //int suma = val1 - val2;
                //String valorTotal = Integer.toString(suma);
                //et_filas.setText(valorTotal);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}

public void buscar(View view){
    cmdingresar.setEnabled(false);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message3).setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
    builder.setMessage("¿Desar buscar por Marca?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            tbldatos.removeAllViews();
            tableDynamic.addHeader(header);
            String url = "http://192.168.*.*/oficina/buscar_vehiculos1.php?Marca_Vehiculo=" + et_busqueda.getText().toString();
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    tableDynamic.backgroundHeader(Color.BLUE);
                    tableDynamic.backgroundData(Color.RED, Color.YELLOW);
                    tableDynamic.lineColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tableDynamic.textColorData(Color.WHITE);
                    tableDynamic.textColorHeader(Color.MAGENTA);
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            LayoutInflater reg1 = getLayoutInflater();
                            View registro = reg1.inflate(R.layout.tabla, null, false);
                            colFilas = registro.findViewById(R.id.colFilas);
                            colTipo = registro.findViewById(R.id.colTipo);
                            colMarca = registro.findViewById(R.id.colMarca);
                            colModelo = registro.findViewById(R.id.colModelo);
                            colFilas.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Filas"));
                            colTipo.setText(jsonObject.getString("Tipo_Vehiculo"));
                            colMarca.setText(jsonObject.getString("Marca_Vehiculo"));
                            colModelo.setText(jsonObject.getString("Modelo_Vehiculo"));
                            tbldatos.addView(registro);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            String url = "http://192.168.*.*/oficina/buscar_vehiculos2.php?N_Filas="+et_busqueda.getText().toString();
            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    if (response.length() == 1){
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.get(0).toString());
                            et_filas.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Filas"));
                            et_tipo.setText(jsonObject.getString("Tipo_Vehiculo"));
                            et_marca.setText(jsonObject.getString("Marca_Vehiculo"));
                            et_modelo.setText(jsonObject.getString("Modelo_Vehiculo"));
                            et_activo.setText(jsonObject.getString("Activo"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Frmmarca.this, "Esta campo no ha sido ingresado aún", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        et_busqueda.setText("");
                        et_busqueda.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setTitle("Oficina");
    alert.show();
}

private void modificardatos (String URL) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Datos modificados satisfactoriamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            limpiardatos();
            mostrardatos();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parametros.put("Tipo_Vehiculo",et_tipo.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Marca_Vehiculo",et_marca.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Modelo_Vehiculo",et_modelo.getText().toString());
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void eliminardatos (String URL) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Datos eliminados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            limpiardatos();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String a = "0";
            et_activo.setText(a);
            parametros.put("N_Filas",et_filas.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Activo",et_activo.getText().toString());
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void limpiardatos(){
    tbldatos.removeAllViews();
    tableDynamic.addHeader(header);
    tableDynamic.backgroundHeader(Color.BLUE);
    tableDynamic.backgroundData(Color.RED, Color.YELLOW);
    tableDynamic.lineColor(Color.BLACK);
    tableDynamic.textColorData(Color.WHITE);
    tableDynamic.textColorHeader(Color.MAGENTA);
    et_busqueda.setText("");
    et_filas.setText("");
    et_tipo.setText("");
    et_marca.setText("");
    et_modelo.setText("");
    llenarSpinner();
    et_marca.requestFocus();
}

private void salir(){
    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, Mdimenu1.class);
    //startActivity(intent);
    //finish();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
}
```

pienso que el error puede ser en el ejecutar servicio, al momento de pinchar en el cmdingresar "INGRESAR", que graba los datos en la tabla, la cual lo realiza bien, (salvo con la excepción que mencione anteriormente que la graba dos veces lo mismo, ya que el campo clave es el ID que va incrementadose" posteriormente llama a datos en el cual llena los datos ingresados en la grilla, después realiza la pregunta Insertar Datos, si desea seguir realizando el proceso y por último el llamado de los datos y que los muestre en la grilla (todos),

favor de verlo y asesorarme soy nuevo en estas lides y me gusta aprender, desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Es importante que agregues lo que realiza datos(); , para dar una respuesta más acertada.

Comment: @Jorgesys muy buenas, te comento que datos, realiza el desplazamiento de los datos ya grabados en la tabla (cajas de texto) y posteriormente es llevado a la grilla, es prácticamente el mismo procedimiento que realizo en java, pero en NetBeans

Comment: estuve realizando algunas pruebas, y deje en comentario datos, insertar y llenarSpinner y graba bien los datos, pero al dejar sin comentario el insertar y realice la consulta al usuario que si desea seguir ingresando graba dos veces los datos, por ejemplo Fila 3, Marca Kia, Tipo Camioneta, modelo Frontier, no sé si el problema estará en el ejecutarservicio, ojala que me puedan asesorar y desde ya muchas gracias